# Twitter rss feed 401 - unauthorisation

Tags: java, api, authentication, twitter

I have a public twitter account and this is the rss feed for it:

http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline/150784631.rss

The problem is, im getting an http 401 whenever im trying to access it.

Can anybody explain how to stop this - and get it to work either with authentication or without!

Cheers

Comment: Wait, this doesn't sound right. friends_timeline is usually accessed like this:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends_timeline.rss

and it gives you your friends' timelines. Where did you get the RSS link above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need a Twitter API username/password to access this feed.

Comment: I want to access the status updates programatically without authentication ideally...

This works but isnt in rss format :

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=cicsdemo

Comment: Just change .xml to .rss

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=cicsdemo